# Add labels to d3 line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am using D3.js to create a simple line graph.

```
<div>
    <h6>Price Over Time</h6>
    <div id="priceOverTimeChart"></div>
</div>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#priceOverTimeChart")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);


    });
```

The data for the line graph uses the following data format:

```
26-Apr-12,0.048
25-Apr-12,0.048
24-Apr-12,0.048
```

I would like to add an optional string to each record so it looks like:

```
26-Apr-12,0.048, "product 1 launch",
25-Apr-12,0.048, "product 2",
24-Apr-12,0.048, "product 3"
26-Apr-12,0.048, null
25-Apr-12,0.048, null
24-Apr-12,0.048, null
```

The graph would then look something like this with the labels on it:

[Graph with optional labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBy8D.jpg)

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending texts to the corresponding x, y position will do the trick.

Please refer this working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elangobharathi/Lqbcye5u/5/)

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) - paddingForText })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.close) + paddingForText })
.attr("fill", "red")
.text(function(d) { return d.notes });
```